# Redis crashing without any log errors

Tags: redis

I'm debugging some weird behavior in my redis, where it's crashing each 2 days more or less, but not showing any errors whatsoever, only this on the logs:

```
1:C 10 Sep 2020 15:44:14.517 # Configuration loaded
1:M 10 Sep 2020 15:44:14.522 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 10 Sep 2020 15:44:14.522 # Server initialized
1:M 10 Sep 2020 15:44:14.524 * Ready to accept connections
1:C 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.751 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.751 # Redis version=6.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.751 # Configuration loaded
1:M 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.757 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.757 # Server initialized
1:M 12 Sep 2020 13:20:23.758 * Ready to accept connections
```

That's all redis says to me.

I have lots of RAM available, but I have redis running as a single instance on a docker container, could the lack of processing power cause this? Should I use multiple nodes? I don't want to setup a cluster just to find out the problem was another, how can I trace down the actually cause of the problem?

Comment: Assuming you run it on Linux (do you?) you can have a look to the system journal: `journalctl -xe` and scroll it up

Comment: Redis is running on Alpine Linux v3.12 in a container, doesn't have journalctl. I ran journalctl on the host and shows nothings relevant.

Comment: I may only recommend you to try ubuntu container for Redis as Alpine uses a different libc and this theoretically might be an issue to some applications

Comment: Are you using any Docker management system such as Rancher, Kubernetes, Docker Swarm etc. Is it just redis re-starting or the container is also re-starting (check via docker ps command)?

Comment: @VikramRawat The container is also restarting. I'm not using any container management system, just docker.

Comment: Do you have any hard limit defined around resource usage... for instance CPU, Memory that the conatiner can use. Which redis image are you using. Can you get into the running container and checks logs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, it was exactly what I thought it was not: a memory leak!

I had 16GB that was slowly being consumed until redis crashed with no warnings, nor the operating system/docker. I fixed the app that caused the leak and the problem was gone.